# Loginv() in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Apparently, Power BI doesn’t have LogInv() functionality.

I have three columns, the probability, mean, and standard deviation. Is there a way to create the loginv column using the values from the three columns?

Answer (score 0):

It's called [NORM.INV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/norm-inv-dax).

Example:

```
LogInv = NORM.INV([Probability column], [Mean column], [Standard_dev column])
```

Comment: Thank you the reply. But Norm.Inc and LogInv are not the same. I am not getting the correct value when using Norm.Inv

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.

I used
EXP(mean + standard deviation*NORM.S.inv(Probability)).

That got me the same value as LOGINV(probability, mean, standard deviation).